# does cocoalibspotify play "nice" with the built in Iphone media player?

Tags: iphone, spotify

once again I'm here with my daily question regarding Spotify...

So, in my app, I want to have the option of the user being able to either play music from Spotify or to play music from their own IPhone media library. However, since I added the Spotify framework, whenever I am testing my app and try to load a scene that has anything to do with the MediaPicker (whether it has a link to a view controller with the media picker or if the view controller for the scene selected has media picker code inside of it) I get the following error (the redacted stuff in the error is just the name of my app) 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBtJh.jpg)

So my question is, can I have both Spotify and the IPod functionality inside of my app? Or is it one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. However, your screenshot has the stack trace on the left hidden, and you need to set a breakpoint to break on exceptions. As far as the log goes, it doesn't look like it's anything to do with either CocoaLibSpotify *or* MediaPicker.

Comment: thanks. I will look at the breakpoints. The weird thing about the log is, all of those "unknown classes" are definitely in the project - and work perfectly in the version of my project without the cocoalibspotify .. for one view controller that produced this error, I made a new copy, but with ONLY MeidaPicker references removed, and it worked, which is why I thought the media picker and cocoalibspotify may not mesh.